# Flask AJAX Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, python, flask

I'm trying to make the jQuery UI autocomplete widget work with the Flask framework.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0.1//EN" "http://w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type=text/javascript>
  $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
  </script>

  <style>
  .ui-autocomplete-loading {
    background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat;
  }
  </style> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $( "#university" ).autocomplete({
      source: $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/_search_university",
        {search: $('input[name="university"]').val()}),
      minLength: 2,
    });
  });
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="university">University: </label>
    <input id="university", name="university" />
  </div>

</body>
```

And this is my Flask method:

```
@app.route('/_search_university')
def search_university():
    search = request.args.get('search')
    results = session.query(University).filter(name.like('%' + search + '%')).all()
    return jsonify(results)
```

I think I got it right but it doesn't seem to work. As soon as I reload the page the function is called (even without input and with the minLength  = 2), looks for the universities but displays nothing (even when he found the universities).

After the first look-up (right after the page) loads, the widget stops sending requests to the server if when I type more then 2 letters in the field.

Can somebody help me here? I'm just trying to get the most basic usage of the autocomplete widget with AJAX by using Flask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to wrap the `$.getJSON()` in a function which will get executed by the plugin whenever the value of the textfield is changed

```
source: function( request, response ) {
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/_search_university", {
        search: request
    }, response);
}
```

Now depending on what you are returning from the server, the above may suffice. However if you need to filter or map the data in order for autocomplete to display it you will need to use the `$.map()` function to transform the data to a format acceptable by autocomplete

```
source: function( request, response ) {
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/_search_university", {
            search: request
        }, function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data.results, function( item ) {
                return {
                    label: item.name,
                    value: item.id
                }
            }));
        });
}
```

If you provide me, with the JSON that your server returns, I can be more specific

Check http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source to see more information

Comment: the only problem I'm having now is that the server side doesn't recognize my search variable anymore. I get the error that search = None?

Comment: if you are using Chrome, open the developer tools and go to the network tab. When you type something in the textfield, you should see new requests coming in. check the request url to see that it is correct

Comment: Since you answered this question so amazingly I was wondering if you maybe could take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438524/object20object-validation-plugin-flask :)