# TypeError when using a like query

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm working on a Python application using Flask/SQLAlchemy on a PostgreSQL database. Trying to implement a Flask / jQuery autocomplete search form as described here [Flask AJAX Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310644/flask-ajax-autocomplete)

In my _base template I have:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#searchfood" ).autocomplete({

            source: function( request, response ) {
                    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/_search_food", {
                        search: request
                    }, function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data.results, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item.name,
                                value: item.id
                            }
                        }));
                    });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And in app.py:

```
@app.route('/_search_food')
def search_food():
    search = request.args.get('search')
    results = Foods.query.filter(Foods.name.like('%' + search + '%')).all()
    return jsonify(results)
```

The Ajax call seems to work, since console shows triggers to search_food however, as well if I browse the page directly http://localhost:5000/_search_food?search%5Bterm%5D=Mar with a 500 error: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects`. Triggered by the results query:

```
results = Foods.query.filter(Foods.name.like('%' + search + '%')).all()
```

Is it that it doesn't get results from the database? Or do I have to convert the input to a different format? The name object in the Foods model is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`search` is `None` because you don't have such a parameter in your GET request, so `request.args.get('search')` returned the default.

Instead your parameter is called `search[term]`, because jQuery was passed an object with a `term` attribute. Extract it:

```
$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/_search_food", {
    search: request.term
},
```

otherwise jQuery tries to serialise the object using a PHP convention.

Also see the [jQueryUI autocomplete documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source):

> *[...]* The callback gets two arguments:
>
> - A request object, with a single `term` property, which refers to the value currently in the text input.
>
> *[...]*

Note that you cannot just convert the `Food()` objects to JSON. Pick the attribute you want to display in the autocomplete widget; it expects an array of strings or an array of objects with `label` and `value` attributes.

You could use a list comprehension to produce those:

```
results = Foods.query.filter(Foods.name.like('%' + search + '%')).all()
return jsonify(results=[{'label': f.name, 'value': f.id} for f in results])
```

where you use the names as the autocompletion value. Note that `jsonify()` always produces a JSON object, for security reasons, so you need to extract the array on the JavaScript side:

```
$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/_search_food", {
    search: request
}, function( data ) { response(data.results); });
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn. I've added .term and now getting a TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence.

Comment: You cannot convert the `Food()` objects to JSON, no. Pick the values from them that should be auto-completed on.